# how to show contents of section while not having it overflow into another section React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I have a section called Timeline that is overflowing into another section called Contact in my React website.

[image]

What can I do so that all the contents of Timeline show but also do not overflow into another section?

Edit: The lightblue portion is where the Contact section starts

Edit:

```
import React from 'react'
import './app.scss';
import Navbar from "./components/navbar/Navbar"
import Intro from "./components/intro/Intro"
import Menu from "./components/menu/Menu"
import Timeline from './components/timeline/Timeline';
import Contact from "./components/contact/Contact"
import { useState } from "react"
App.jsx
function App() {
  const [menuOpen, setMenuOpen] = useState(false)
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Navbar menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen}/>
      <Menu menuOpen={menuOpen} setMenuOpen={setMenuOpen}/>
      <div className="sections">
        <Intro/>
        <Timeline/>
        <Contact/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

app.scss

```
.app {
    height: 100vh;

    .sections {
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100vh - 70px);
        // background-color: #1F1D36;
        position: relative;
        top: 70px;
        scroll-behavior: smooth;
        display: flex;
        scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
        scrollbar-width: none; // for firefox
        &::-webkit-scrollbar{
            display: none;
        }

        > * {
            width: 100vw;
            height: calc(100vh - 70px);
            scroll-snap-align: start;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the behaviour you want instead is. Do you want to make contact start lower so that the timeline has more space? Do you want to cut off the timeline where contact starts? Do you want a scrollbar in timeline so it doesn't encroach on contact's space?

Comment: yes, exactly I want contact to start lower so that timeline can dynamically increase in space as more events are added

Comment: @Ben I have added some of my code for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `max-height` to `.sections` containing timeline and add `overflow-y:auto`.

This stops the section from expanding extra and makes the content scroll.

Here is a code that you can refer.

```css
*{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child{
  height: calc(100vh - 70px);
}

.child:first-child{
  background: yellow;
  max-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
  overflow-y:auto;
}

.child:last-child{
  background: lightblue;
}

.large{
  height: 900px;
  background: white;
  margin: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="large"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu, thank you for the response! So I added this snipped `.sections:nth-child(2) {
            max-height: calc(100vh - 70px);
            overflow-y:auto;
        }` 
but it still had no effect, it still overflowing

Comment: Is 2nd child is the component having timeline?

Comment: Yes, If you see my code in my edited answer, I have included the order of all the sections, it goes Intro, Timeline, and Contact

Comment: wait, it just worked i went and edited the css file specifc for the timeline. Thank you!